# Laravel add new properties to returned API resource object does not work

Tags: laravel, api, object, jsonapi-resources

I have below Laravel controller methods, I need to customize the returned result, but I have problem as below:

```
 public function getCart(CartProductsRequest $request)
    {
        try {
            $carts = json_decode($request->cart);
            $products = [];
            $total = 0;
            $allCurrency = "";
            foreach ($carts as $key => $cart) {

                $product = new  ProductResource(Product::findOrFail($cart->productId));

                $total += $product->finalPrice * $cart->quantity;
                $product->qty = $cart->quantity;
                $product->inStock = $product->inStock();
                $product->totalPrice =  $cart->quantity *  $product->finalPrice;
                $products[] = $product;
                $allCurrency = $product->currency->symbol;
            }

            $cart = ['products' => $products, 'total' => round($total, 2), 'currency' => $allCurrency];

            return JsonResponse::respondSuccess(trans(JsonResponse::MSG_SUCCESS), $cart);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return JsonResponse::respondError($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The result (products) does not contain the new added probertites like qty
, I don't know way,

The API resource is (the fields returned):

```
   public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name_en' => $this->name_en,
            'name_ar' => $this->name_ar,
            'slug' => $this->slug,
            'details' => $this->details,
            'currency' => $this->currency,
            'offer' => $this->offer->first(),
            'brand' => $this->brand,
            'category' => $this->category,
            'specifications' => SpesificationResource::collection($this->specifications),
            'merchant' => $this->merchant,
            'images' => count($this->images) > 0 ? ImageResource::collection($this->images) : asset("/images/default.png"),
            "price" => $this->price,
            "finalPrice" => $this->offer->first() ? $this->price - ($this->price * $this->offer->first()->discount / 100) : $this->price,
            'quantity' => $this->quantity,
            'inStock' => $this->inStock(),
            'status' => $this->status,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        ];
    }
```

The result is :

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "content": {
        "products": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "nameEn": "Device 1",
                "nameAr": "\u062c\u0647\u0627\u0632 1",
                "slug": "device-1",
                "details": "Veniam quis accusamus est ea ad ipsa hic. Distinctio assumenda quibusdam magnam nobis aut aliquam nesciunt. Quia unde sapiente maiores temporibus rerum eum. Porro debitis est error quia.",
                "currency": {
                    "id": 92,
                    "nameAr": "\u0627\u0644\u0644\u064a\u0631\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u062a\u0631\u0643\u064a\u0629",
                    "nameEn": "Turkish Lira",
                    "code": "TRY",
                    "symbol": "TL",
                    "image": null,
                    "status": 1,
                    "isDefault": 1,
                    "createdAt": null,
                    "updatedAt": null
                },
                "offer": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "nameAr": "offer 1",
                    "nameEn": "offer 1",
                    "details": null,
                    "image": null,
                    "status": 1,
                    "discount": "20.00",
                    "addedBy": 1,
                    "updatedBy": null,
                    "startDate": "2021-08-05 08:29:35",
                    "endDate": null,
                    "createdAt": "2021-08-05T08:29:35.000000Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2021-08-05T08:29:35.000000Z",
                    "pivot": {
                        "productId": 1,
                        "offerId": 1
                    }
                },
                "brand": {
                    "id": 7,
                    "nameAr": "Kasandra Volkman",
                    "nameEn": "Nathanial Larson",
                    "photo": null,
                    "createdAt": "2021-08-05T08:21:34.000000Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2021-08-05T08:29:34.000000Z"
                },
                "category": {
                    "id": 6,
                    "nameAr": "Miss Verna Breitenberg V",
                    "nameEn": "Laurel Wehner IV",
                    "details": "Dolor debitis itaque maiores sed nihil magnam. Illo molestiae quas sed nihil possimus ut. Non qui enim possimus officia quaerat quod voluptate.",
                    "image": "111628152906.jpg",
                    "status": 1,
                    "slug": "laurel-wehner-iv",
                    "lft": 0,
                    "rgt": 0,
                    "parentId": null
                },
                "specifications": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "nameEn": "Vance Miller",
                        "nameAr": "Dr. Wellington Jones",
                        "value": "test",
                        "image": null,
                        "createdAt": "2021-08-05T07:53:35.000000Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-08-05T08:29:35.000000Z"
                    }
                ],
                "merchant": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "merchant",
                    "email": "merchant@merchants.com",
                    "phone": "1111",
                    "firstName": "merchant",
                    "lastName": "merchant",
                    "cityId": 1,
                    "street": null,
                    "buildNumber": null,
                    "houseNumber": null,
                    "status": 1,
                    "emailVerifiedAt": "2021-08-05T08:29:34.000000Z",
                    "roleId": 2,
                    "profilePhotoPath": null,
                    "createdBy": null,
                    "updatedBy": null,
                    "currencyId": null,
                    "createdAt": "2021-08-05T08:29:34.000000Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2021-08-05T08:29:34.000000Z",
                    "deletedAt": null,
                    "profilePhotoUrl": "https:\/\/ui-avatars.com\/api\/?name=merchant&color=7F9CF5&background=EBF4FF"
                },
                "images": [
                    {
                        "id": 12,
                        "name": "\/images\/products\/1_1.png",
                        "orderingShow": 1,
                        "createdAt": "2021-08-05T08:39:10.000000Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-08-05T08:39:10.000000Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 13,
                        "name": "\/images\/products\/1_2.png",
                        "orderingShow": 2,
                        "createdAt": "2021-08-05T08:39:10.000000Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-08-05T08:39:10.000000Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 14,
                        "name": "\/images\/products\/1_3.png",
                        "orderingShow": 3,
                        "createdAt": "2021-08-05T08:39:10.000000Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-08-05T08:39:10.000000Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 15,
                        "name": "\/images\/products\/1_4.png",
                        "orderingShow": 4,
                        "createdAt": "2021-08-05T08:39:10.000000Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-08-05T08:39:10.000000Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 16,
                        "name": "\/images\/products\/1_5.png",
                        "orderingShow": 5,
                        "createdAt": "2021-08-05T08:39:10.000000Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-08-05T08:39:10.000000Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 17,
                        "name": "\/images\/products\/1_6.png",
                        "orderingShow": 6,
                        "createdAt": "2021-08-05T08:39:10.000000Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-08-05T08:39:10.000000Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 18,
                        "name": "\/images\/products\/1_7.png",
                        "orderingShow": 7,
                        "createdAt": "2021-08-05T08:39:10.000000Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-08-05T08:39:10.000000Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 19,
                        "name": "\/images\/products\/1_8.png",
                        "orderingShow": 8,
                        "createdAt": "2021-08-05T08:39:10.000000Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-08-05T08:39:10.000000Z"
                    }
                ],
                "price": "100.00",
                "finalPrice": 80,
                "quantity": 20,
                "inStock": true,
                "status": 1,
                "createdAt": "2021-08-05T08:21:35.000000Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-08-05T08:42:43.000000Z"
            }
        ],
        "total": 0,
        "currency": "TL"
    },
    "message": "responses.msg_success",
    "status": 200
}
```

**Can you help me please to determine the problem??  (I need the qty in the result) Or if there is another way to map the result**

Comment: What is the problem ? That you only get the last product all the time ? If that is the case, try doing `$products[] = $product->toArray();` before closing the `}`.

Comment: It's does not work dear  @matiaslaurti